# Swap Two Columns with If Condition

Tags: excel

**I want to swap value for where A1 > B1. How Can i get my expected result**
**-----------------------------------------------**

```
    A   |  B
  ______|______
1  10   | 20
  ______|______
2  50   | 40
  ______|______
3  60   | 70
  ______|______
4  80   | 50
  ______|______
5  20   | 22
  ______|______
6  50   | 10
  ______|______
7  80   | 50
  ______|______
8  50   | 10
  ______|______
```

**If A1 > B1 condition is true then Structure look like this**

```
    A   |  B
  ______|______
1  10   | 20
  ______|______
2  40   | 50
  ______|______
3  60   | 70
  ______|______
4  50   | 80
  ______|______
5  20   | 22
  ______|______
6  10   | 50
  ______|______
7  50   | 80
  ______|______
8  10   | 50
  ______|______
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    A   |  B    |  C   |  B   
  ______|______ |______|_____
1  10   | 20    |      |
  ______|______ |______|_____
2  40   | 50    |      |
  ______|______ |______|_____
3  60   | 70    |      |
  ______|______ |______|_____
4  50   | 80    |      |
  ______|______ |______|_____
5  20   | 22    |      |
  ______|______ |______|_____
```

Formula in C1 will be

```
=IF(A1>B1; B1; A1)
```

Formula in B1 will be

```
=IF(A1>B1; A1; B1)
```

Now you just need to hide the other two columns :)